# Is there a way to group notifications by app?

Tags: root-access, notifications, notification-bar, miui

So, my phone is running MIUI 12.5(rooted if it matters) and some apps just push individual notifications so each notification I get, shows up in its own bubble instead of showing them all under a group of notifications for this same app.

It's really hard since it takes up all my screen and if I want to search for notifications from a certain app I have to go over all the other notifications from the other apps..

Is there a way to force notifications from the same app to be grouped together in my notification bar?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of notification history/recent notification apps that do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Pixel 4a running stock Android 11 (YMMV on MIUI)

Download and install from Play Store [Notifications Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.east_hino.notification_organizer)  . App description includes

> Organize notifications by app

Grant the permissions asked and optionally toggle unread badge count and tool bar fixed (not sure what this does but I enabled it).

On getting notifications, a tiny bell icon flashes in status bar and you see notifications by app in the notification bar (relevant portion of screen shot below)

[image]

You can access the notifications through the app also (for easy access, drop app widget to home screen)

[image]

Note that only 5 apps are supported (in the notification bar, while no such restrictions apply to app interface) , so you would need to add apps to *exclusion list* to exclude them.

P.S. The app is being well maintained with last update of June end. In case it doesn't work as advertised, maybe you should approach developer. I am not affiliated with it.

Comment: not very comfortable.. I'm looking for something that would replace the shading...

Comment: What do you mean by shading? In any case, I will let the answer be, it may help someone else, because it addresses the core concern of organization by app

Comment: by shading, I mean the menu of notification which rolls from top. There are applications which replace the shading with their own(like power shading for example) but none seem to force group by app..

Comment: Got it. But then, this requirement should have been a part of the question, especially a bounty one. If that was the case, I wouldn't have answered at all! Anyway, do post your solution if you get one and in future please make your question as complete as possible so that you get what you want and the time and effort of one who answers isn't wasted. Best

Answer (score -1):

shortest possible working solution : switch to a stock android based custom ROM. Stock android by default behaves the way you're talking about

Comment: Are you sure? Twitter is pushing each tweet as individual notification, and they cannot be grouped by end-user, even on stock Pixel 3a.

Comment: pixel 3a stock isnt running aosp androd either : by 'stock' i meant AOSP